# C# ListView.Invoke and ListView.FindItemWithText Error

Tags: c#, .net, forms

So I am using **C#** and **Forms**, I have **ListView** with Items and I am trying to **find Item with text**.

I have **seperate threads** in 2 **seperate scripts/classes** (1. MainForm.cs and 2. workWithLists.cs I need to use FindItemWithText in workWithLists.cs) so I need to use **invoke**:

```
ListViewItem v = listView1.Invoke(listView1.FindItemWithText("TestName"));
```

But I have error when I use **Invoke with FindItemWithText:**

`Cannot convert from "System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem" to "System.Delegate"`

**Without** **Invoke**:

```
ListViewItem v = listView1.FindItemWithText("TestName");
```

I don't have any Errors, But when I run the code it gives me Error:

`Invalid multi-thread operation: An attempt was made to access control 'listView1' from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

Please somebody explain to me what am I doing wrong, And how to fix this.

**Calling FindItemWithText from the thread listview1 was made is not an Answer**
: D

Edit: I have this code in MainForm.cs:

```
public static ListView list;
public delegate void FindInListViewDelegate(string name);
public FindInListViewDelegate FindInListView = new FindInListViewDelegate(Find);
        

public ListViewItem Find(string name)
{
     ListViewItem item = list.FindItemWithText(name);
     return item;
}
```

But I am getting Error: `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MainForm.Find(string)'`

I was changing:

```
public ListViewItem Find(string name) {}
```

To:

```
public static ListViewItem Find(string name) {}
```

But then it gives another Error: `'ListViewItem MainForm.Find(string)' has the wrong return type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control.Invoke method, executes a delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

And listView1.FindItemWithText is not a delegate, so in your main thread declare an Action or a delegate and use it in your second thread.

Main thread:

```
public delegate void FindInListViewDelegate(string name);

public FindInListViewDelegate FindInListView = new FindInListViewDelegate(Find);

public ListViewItem Find(string name)
{
    var item = listView1.FindItemWitdhText(name);
    ...
}
```

Secondary thread:

```
myForm.Invoke(myForm.FindInListView, new object[] { nameToSearch });
```

You can use an Action too, I set up a small Console application:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    static public Action<string> FindInListView = (name) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Finding item {name} in ListView");
    };

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => { FindInListView.Invoke("Joan"); });
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like this will work, But I get Error with `public FindInListViewDelegate FindInListView = new FindInListViewMethod(Find)`, Error: `The type or namespace 'FindInListViewMethod could not be found`. I didn't understand with what I should replace the `FindInListViewMethod`

Comment: Sorry, it's FindInListViewDelegate

Comment: Now I am getting Error `A field initializer cannot reference the non static field, method, or property 'MainForm.Din(string)'`, I tried changing `public ListViewItem Find(string name)` to `public static ListViewItem Find(string name)`, But then I am getting Error `'ListViewItem MainForm.Find(string)' has the wrong return type`

Comment: And the Action didn't work, Probably because I also have 2 different scripts/classes, Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I've used a console app to show you an example, remove `static` from the Action.